# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am getting this error when I load each page of my application. I have searched SO and the net to no avail. Any idea how to fix this error?

```
Started GET "/javascripts/jquery.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 16:26:14 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/jquery.js"):
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'

Rendered /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)
```

Comment: Did you by change remove the `jquery-rails` gem from your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my JavaScripts were not in the asset pipeline, but the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `require` statements  in your `application.js` file ?? (before the JS functions add these)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```